# What can be improved on my first haskell program?

Tags: haskell, coding-style

Here is my first Haskell program. What parts would you write in a better way?

```
-- Multiplication table
-- Returns n*n multiplication table in base b

import Text.Printf
import Data.List
import Data.Char

-- Returns n*n multiplication table in base b 
mulTable :: Int -> Int -> String
mulTable n b = foldl (++) (verticalHeader n b w) (map (line n b w) [0..n])
               where 
                 lo = 2* (logBase (fromIntegral  b)  (fromIntegral n))
                 w = 1+fromInteger (floor lo)

verticalHeader :: Int -> Int -> Int -> String  
verticalHeader n b w = (foldl (++) tableHeader columnHeaders)
                        ++ "\n" 
                        ++ minusSignLine 
                        ++ "\n"
                   where
                     tableHeader = replicate (w+2) ' '
                     columnHeaders = map (horizontalHeader b w) [0..n]
                     minusSignLine = concat ( replicate ((w+1)* (n+2)) "-" )

horizontalHeader :: Int -> Int -> Int -> String
horizontalHeader b w i = format i b w

line :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> String
line n b w y  = (foldl (++) ((format y b w) ++ "|" ) 
                           (map (element b w y) [0..n])) ++ "\n"

element :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> String  
element b w y x = format  (y * x) b w

toBase :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
toBase b v = toBase' [] v where
  toBase' a 0 = a
  toBase' a v = toBase' (r:a) q where (q,r) = v `divMod` b

toAlphaDigits :: [Int] -> String
toAlphaDigits = map convert where
  convert n | n < 10    = chr (n + ord '0')
            | otherwise = chr (n + ord 'a' - 10)

format :: Int -> Int -> Int -> String
format v b w = concat spaces ++ digits ++ " "
               where 
                   digits  = if v == 0 
                             then "0" 
                             else toAlphaDigits ( toBase b v )
                   l = length digits
                   spaceCount = if (l > w) then  0 else (w-l) 
                   spaces = replicate spaceCount " "
```

Comment: Do you have tests? They might reveal some improvements on their own.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- To make the tabularity of the computation more obvious, I would pass the list `[0..n]` to the `line` function rather than passing `n`.
- I would further split out the computation of the horizontal and vertical axes so that they are passed as arguments to `mulTable` rather than computed there.
- Haskell is higher-order, and almost none of the computation has to do with multiplication.  So I would change the name of `mulTable` to `binopTable` and pass the actual multiplication in as a parameter.
- Finally, the formatting of individual numbers is repetitious.  Why not pass `\x -> format x b w` as a parameter, eliminating the need for `b` and `w`?

The net effect of the changes I am suggesting is that you build a general higher-order function for creating tables for binary operators.  Its type becomes something like

```
binopTable :: (i -> String) -> (i -> i -> i) -> [i] -> [i] -> String
```

and you wind up with a much more reusable function—for example, Boolean truth tables should be a piece of cake.

**Higher-order and reusable** is the Haskell Way.

Answer (score 11):

You don't use anything from `import Text.Printf`.

Stylistically, you use more parentheses than necessary.  Haskellers tend to find code more readable when it's cleaned of extraneous stuff like that.  Instead of something like `h x = f (g x)`, write `h = f . g`.

Nothing here really requires `Int`; `(Integral a) => a` ought to do.

`foldl (++) x xs` == `concat $ x : xs`: I trust the built-in `concat` to work better than your implementation.
Also, you should prefer `foldr` when the function is lazy in its second argument, as `(++)` is – because Haskell is lazy, this reduces stack space (and also works on infinite lists).
Also, `unwords` and `unlines` are shortcuts for `intercalate " "` and `concat . map (++ "\n")` respectively, i.e. "join with spaces" and "join with newlines (plus trailing newline)"; you can replace a couple things by those.

Unless you use big numbers, `w = length $ takeWhile (<= n) $ iterate (* b) 1` is probably faster.  Or, in the case of a lazy programmer, let `w = length $ toBase b n`.

`concat ( (replicate ((w+1)* (n+2)) "-" )` == `replicate ((w+1) * (n+2)) '-'` – not sure how you missed this one, you got it right just a couple lines up.

You do the same thing with `concat spaces`, too.  However, wouldn't it be easier to actually use the `Text.Printf` import and write `printf "%*s " w digits`?

Answer (score 5):

Norman Ramsey gave excellent high-level (design) suggestions; Below are some low-level ones:

- First, consult with [HLint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint). HLint is a friendly program that gives you rudimentary advice on how to improve your Haskell code!

  - In your case HLint gives 7 suggestions. (mostly about redundant brackets)
  - Modify your code according to HLint's suggestions until it likes what you feed it.
- More HLint-like stuff:

  - `concat (replicate i "-")`. Why not `replicate i '-'`?
- Consult with [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BString%5D+-%3E+String) whenever there is reason to believe that a function you need is already available in Haskell's libraries. Haskell comes with tons of useful functions so Hoogle should come in handy quite often.

  - Need to concatenate strings? Search for `[String] -> String`, and voila you found `concat`. Now go replace all those folds.
  - The previous search also suggested `unlines`. Actually, this even better suits your needs. It's magic!
- Optional: pause and thank in your heart to Neil M for making Hoogle and HLint, and thank others for making other good stuff like Haskell, bridges, tennis balls, and sanitation.
- Now, for every function that takes several arguments of the same type, make it clear which means what, by giving them descriptive names. This is better than comments, but you can still use both.

So

```
-- Returns n*n multiplication table in base b 
mulTable :: Int -> Int -> String
mulTable n b =
```

becomes

```
mulTable :: Int -> Int -> String
mulTable size base =
```

- To soften the extra characters blow of the previous suggestion: When a function is only used once, and is not very useful by itself, put it inside its caller's scope in its `where` clause, where it could use the callers' variables, saving you the need to pass everything to it.

So

```
line :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> String
line n b w y =
  concat
  $ format y b w
  : "|"
  : map (element b w y) [0 .. n]

element :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> String  
element b w y x = format (y * x) b w
```

becomes

```
line :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> String
line n b w y =
  concat
  $ format y b w
  : "|"
  : map element [0 .. n]
  where
    element x = format (y * x) b w
```

- You can even move `line` into `mulTable`'s `where` clause; imho, you should.

  - If you find a `where` clause nested inside another `where` clause troubling, then I suggest to change your indentation habits. My recommendation is to use consistent indentation of always 2 or always 4 spaces. Then you can easily see, everywhere, where the `where` in the other `where` is at. ok

Below's what it looks like (with a few other changes in style):

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char

mulTable :: Int -> Int -> String
mulTable size base =
  unlines $
  [ vertHeaders
  , minusSignsLine
  ] ++ map line [0 .. size]
  where
    vertHeaders =
      concat
      $ replicate (cellWidth + 2) ' '
      : map horizontalHeader [0 .. size]
    horizontalHeader i = format i base cellWidth
    minusSignsLine = replicate ((cellWidth + 1) * (size + 2)) '-'
    cellWidth = length $ toBase base (size * size)
    line y =
      concat
      $ format y base cellWidth
      : "|"
      : map element [0 .. size]
      where
        element x = format (y * x) base cellWidth

toBase :: Integral i => i -> i -> [i]
toBase base
  = reverse
  . map (`mod` base)
  . takeWhile (> 0)
  . iterate (`div` base)

toAlphaDigit :: Int -> Char
toAlphaDigit n
  | n < 10    = chr (n + ord '0')
  | otherwise = chr (n + ord 'a' - 10)

format :: Int -> Int -> Int -> String
format v b w =
  spaces ++ digits ++ " "
  where 
    digits
      | v == 0    = "0"
      | otherwise = map toAlphaDigit (toBase b v)
    spaces = replicate (w - length digits) ' '
```

Answer (score 4):

0) add a main function :-) at least rudimentary

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Control.Monad (liftM)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- liftM (map read) $ getArgs
  case args of
    (n:b:_) -> putStrLn $ mulTable n b
    _       -> putStrLn "usage: nntable n base"
```

1) run `ghc` or `runhaskell` with `-Wall`; run through `hlint`.

While `hlint` doesn't suggest anything special here (only some redundant brackets), `ghc` will tell you that you don't actually need `Text.Printf` here...

2) try running it with base = 1 or base = 0 or base = -1

Comment: Surely I'm not the only one who mostly runs code through ghci, and only adds a `main` as an afterthought...

Comment: `ghci` is great, but I run only small snippets there... (yes, `:load` is helpful too).

Comment: I run tiny pieces of my code through GHCi to test it, but I always have a main declarations during the end stages so I can run the entire program with runghc and test it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want multiline comments use:

```
{-  A multiline
   comment -}
```

Also, never use `foldl`, use `foldl'` instead, in cases where you are dealing with large lists which must be folded. It is more memory efficient.

Comment: `foldl'` if the function is strict, `foldr` if it is lazy.

Answer (score 1):

A brief comments saying what each function does, its arguments and return value, is always good. I had to read the code pretty carefully to fully make sense of it.

Some would say if you do that, explicit type signatures may not be required. That's an aesthetic question, I don't have a strong opinion on it.

One minor caveat: if you do remove the type signatures, you'll automatically get the polymorphic `Integral` support ephemient mentioned, but you will still need one around `toAlphaDigits` because of the infamous "monomorphism restriction."

Comment: I'm of the opinion that, after good function naming and explicit type signatures, comments might not be necessary.  And I'd rather express myself in Haskell pseudo-code (which happens to look exactly like Haskell code) than in English.  But, as you note, that's up to the author's aesthetic taste.

Comment: That's true, I guess it just places more emphasis on names, especially parameter names. For example, `verticalHeader n b w` doesn't really jump out and shout what one should expect that function to do.